# Devise If logged in automatically send to home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a base installation of Devise with everything setup and working correctly. I have a 'welcome' page and a 'dashboard' page which only logged in users can get to.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make all logged in users automatically skip the landing page and land straight on the dashboard when they come back to the site.

e.g.

- I sign up from the landing page
- I'm logged in
- I close off chrome and go for food
- I open chrome and go to the root url (example.com)
- I get presented with my dashboard instead of the welcome page as I am logged in.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do a simple check in the controller for if the session is active and if so `redirect_to dashboard_path`

I havent used devise in forever so I don't remember if they have a built in `current_user` ([see the current_user setup here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch)) method or not, but checking if that is `nil` would be a good check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an **after sign in devise method** in your **application controller**:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  your_after_sign_in_path
end
```

That should redirect all users to your_after_sign_in_path after they sign in.

Comment: In your case, use your dashboard_path

Comment: I currently already have this within my controller, all this is doing is forwarding my 'login' button on my landing page to my dashboard. I'm trying to make it so that users automatically end up on my dashboard instead of the landing page itself